# Закрытие Full-screen картинки свайпом вверх

Tags: android, activity, android-viewpager, imageview, swipe

Есть Активность с картинкой, которая запускается из другой активности. Хочу сделать закрытие активности (с переходом на предыдущую) с красивым эффектом, как это реализовано в соц сетях. Но не могу найти инфу об этом (не знаю как правильно загуглить, вот и не нахожу).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лично я вот такую либу юзаю - она легко встривается и достаточно гибкая в настройке:

https://github.com/r0adkll/Slidr

Пример использования и описание есть в ридми. Также там есть вот эта гифка с показом работы либы:

https://github.com/r0adkll/Slidr/raw/master/images/slidr_gif.gif

Comment: Немного не понятно. Как прописать свайп вверх? это в .position() или где?

Comment: @НикитаШаврин, да, `position`. По идее как-то так: `.position(SlidrPosition.TOP)`

Comment: @НикитаШаврин поясните вопрос. По идея активити сама закроется по жесту, т.е. её `finish()` метод вызовется.

Comment: у меня не хочет работать. У меня ViewPager. И когда я свайплю, ничего не происходит... 
Вот Gist

[Гист](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b782f8e9676562ab001bd5629cbd1bc4)

Comment: @НикитаШаврин, покажите код. У меня с ViewPager сё работает: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cuberto.tappawards

Comment: [Ссылка на код](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b782f8e9676562ab001bd5629cbd1bc4)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59201/discussion-between---and-).

Comment: @НикитаШаврин, не, в чаты я не хожу - религия не позволяет) Я могу предположить, что проблема во фрагментах - попробуйте переписать адаптер не используя фрагменты. Или попробовать убрать строки для фулскрина. Также надо проверить, что вы все пункты из описания либы выполнили. Там в стилях что-то было.

Comment: Ну я не использовал:
.primaryColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary)
.secondaryColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.secondary)
.listener(new SlidrListener(){...})

Первые 2 не нужны, а 3й - я немного не знаю что там писать.

Comment: Ну, без SlidrConfig оно работает)

Comment: @НикитаШаврин, раз работает, значит и ответ принять можно)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: А как можно сделать так, что бы предыдущая активность отображалась как бы на заднем фоне, как на гифке в примере. А то у меня чисто фон серый...

Comment: Можно. Смотрите в стили в ридми либы и проверьте фон в активити/фрагментах